# Calculate the average of rows with similar values in R

Tags: r, mean

I am working with a dataset regarding unemployment rate across English regions over a 22 months period.

I split the original dataset in two: one includes the regions with the higher unemployment rate (**df1**), and the other includes the one with the lower unemployment rate (**df2**).

The **desired output** is the same for both of them, so I'll just post the structure of **df1**:

**df1** currently includes the unemployment rate per month across five regions:

- North East
- London
- Yorkshire and The Humber
- East Midlands
- West Midlands

I want to calculate the average unemployment rate of every region for every month (i.e. the average of North East, London (etc.) for Jan 19, Feb 20, (all the way to Oct 20).

The point of this being, once I summarise the average unemployment rate of all the regions into one, I can have a single plot instead of five different ones.

Expected output:

```
Date | Region | Unemployment rate
01-2019 | ABC | AJan_19+B_Jan19+C_Jan19 / 3
02-2019 | ABC | AFeb_19+B_Feb19+C_Feb19 / 3
03-2019 | ABC | AMar_19+B_Feb19+C_Feb19 / 3
```

and so on

So instead of having 5 values for each month (i.e. one value per region), I sum the regions' values and divide them by the number of regions for each month.

Here's the structure of df1

```
structure(list(
Date = structure(c(17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 
  17897, 17928, 17928, 17928, 17928, 17928, 17956, 17956, 17956, 
  17956, 17956, 17987, 17987, 17987, 17987, 17987, 18017, 18017, 
  18017, 18017, 18017, 18048, 18048, 18048, 18048, 18048, 18078, 
  18078, 18078, 18078, 18078, 18109, 18109, 18109, 18109, 18109, 
  18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 
  18170, 18201, 18201, 18201, 18201, 18201, 18231, 18231, 18231, 
  18231, 18231, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18293, 18293, 
  18293, 18293, 18293, 18322, 18322, 18322, 18322, 18322, 18353, 
  18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
  18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18444, 18444, 18444, 18444, 
  18444, 18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 18506, 18506, 18506, 
  18506, 18506, 18536, 18536, 18536, 18536, 18536), class = "Date"), 
Region = structure(c(4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
  9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
  9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
  9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
  9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
  9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
  9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
  9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), 
.Label = c("England", 
    "South East", "South West", "London", "East of England", 
    "East Midlands", "West Midlands", "Yorkshire and The Humber", 
    "North East", "North West"), class = "factor"), 
Unemployment.rate = c(4.2102766429572, 
    4.68247349426148, 5.0708122696351, 5.23113585152962, 5.05625777763551, 
    4.45850956493638, 4.24086209425895, 5.20425572086481, 4.90649662696461, 
    5.58119346747183, 4.36960549219723, 4.02517515965457, 5.07463979478007, 
    4.74861899849302, 5.41295614949722, 4.2765275404374, 4.29397104451947, 
    4.95863831882363, 4.92741739593892, 5.69156027694963, 4.2650375361128, 
    4.23454968410189, 4.79139912788739, 5.02305883708418, 5.5878529496241, 
    4.54049887070026, 4.28118824655063, 4.56621383409869, 5.02948552097342, 
    5.34849310422496, 4.63523851140925, 4.63665149464923, 4.15610221124255, 
    4.28827168334814, 4.97071907922267, 4.63148007856079, 4.50379542173275, 
    3.98279027057451, 4.00981283870947, 5.80674097480643, 4.5449089097835, 
    4.46358064141772, 4.09111105457073, 3.90122545742185, 5.85180583091048, 
    4.50615604436695, 3.65653388653173, 4.4653881330391, 4.08974888999112, 
    6.11361138828401, 4.31177130663949, 3.86911315140672, 4.31748261760943, 
    4.34062792253313, 6.21086689536757, 4.28854311714984, 3.58533538113168, 
    4.43826006085208, 4.47398990035041, 6.11583334445995, 4.4614986334698, 
    3.93320874039025, 4.50210360585639, 4.58329815843159, 6.1811363458787, 
    4.4993016103369, 4.02503140646339, 4.81764323428107, 4.71840892982655, 
    5.61192961811575, 4.66797282030472, 3.76788548732822, 5.02382063022771, 
    4.27033347501753, 5.40098295976569, 4.63121679655635, 3.67161258712684, 
    4.80322174913054, 3.91339590231661, 5.20229523339659, 5.10845457998552, 
    3.97182605242641, 4.85515814694348, 3.78242013517353, 4.97115704468143, 
    4.6437916194869, 4.3194319371037, 4.41226516242903, 3.75797094178592, 
    5.16820059074221, 4.98077486925899, 4.38753537321373, 4.37107017836121, 
    3.98499236263049, 5.15965087736712, 5.2511686249283, 4.39271393019063, 
    4.62628095567074, 4.16298001615593, 6.62714213785116, 5.95104220347072, 
    4.89588411607636, 4.9378241924801, 4.65307341597827, 6.67088507450695, 
    6.33714099073375, 5.32040137455687, 5.402969264185, 5.15177120913334, 
    6.56889233919367)), 
    row.names = c(NA, -110L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can either `format` the 'Date' column to `year-month` or use `as.yearmon` from `zoo`, use that as grouping column along with 'Region', and `summarise` the `mean` of 'Unemployment.rate'

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(year_mon = as.yearmon(Date), Region) %>%  
   summarise(Mean_unemp = mean(Unemployment.rate, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

Or if it is only based on month

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Month = format(Date, "%m"), Region) %>%  
   summarise(Mean_unemp = mean(Unemployment.rate, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

If it is based on 'Region' only

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(Region) %>%
   summarise(Mean_unemp = mean(Unemployment.rate, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

Or group by 'Date'

```
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Date) %>% 
    summarise(Mean = mean(Unemployment.rate))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried your code but it only changed the date column to a month - year format. However everything else stayed the same; I still have 5 unemployment rate values per month, but I need only one per month (hence why I'd like to calculate the average for each month). Also, that would change the date column to a "yearmon" class. Isn't it better to keep it as "date" class for plotting?

Comment: @Lactuca I guess your question was to get the mean for every yearmonth and Region

Comment: @Lactuca the reason is that there is only one unique row per each Region and year-month.  You can check the frequency count with `table` or `count(df1, Region, Date)`

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clear. I want to do the following: pick the unemployment rate value of each region, and divide it by the number of regions. If I do this for every month, I should have one unemployment rate value for every  month instead of X number of values for each month where X = n. of regions. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Lactuca In that case, you need just to group by 'Region'

Comment: I just did but I still need one value per month (so 22 in total). If I group by region it only shows one value per region (5 in total) :s

Comment: @Lactuca Can you update your post with the expected

Comment: @Lactuca DO you need `mutate` instead of `summarise`

Comment: @Lactuca Grouping by 'Date' gives 22 rows `df1 %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(Unemployment.rate))`

Comment: That's exactly it! Thanks a lot!  Can I ask how I can change it if I wanted to do the same but SUM every months' value? I am gonna have to do that for a different dataset, I am asking now so I don't create a different topic for it. I tried looking into sum() but I don't think it should go along summarise()

Comment: @Lactuca Just change the `mean` to `sum`.  It would go along with `summarise`.  check `df1 %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(Sum = sum(Unemployment.rate))`

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`:

```
#Code
df1$Date <- format(df1$Date,'%b-%Y')
#Aggregate
out <- aggregate(Unemployment.rate~.,data=df1,mean,na.rm=T)
```

Output:

```
head(out)
      Date Region Unemployment.rate
1 Apr-2019 London          4.276528
2 Apr-2020 London          4.631217
3 Aug-2019 London          4.631480
4 Aug-2020 London          5.251169
5 Dec-2019 London          4.288543
6 Feb-2019 London          4.458510
```

Another option per month:

```
#Code
df1$Date <- format(df1$Date,'%b')
#Aggregate
out <- aggregate(Unemployment.rate~.,data=df1,mean,na.rm=T)
```

Comment: Duck you're a saint. Sorry I didn't make myself clear though; I want to do the following: pick the unemployment rate value of each region, and divide it by the number of regions. If I do this for every month, I should have one unemployment rate value for every  month instead of X number of values for each month where X = n. of regions. Does that make sense?